# Flutter Webview I can't interact

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, webview

I am using webview_flutter. There are missing parts on the page and I can't interact like opening the side tab.
Here is my code:

```
late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://www.*******.com/'),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it just add this line

```
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
```

new code is:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://www.*********.com/'),
      );
  }
```